# PHP use a variable in a string

Tags: php, html, string, variables

I hava a problem at my PHP script!
I want to do something like

```
echo "hello $var";
```

And the output should be "hello $var". So it should not take the value of $var, but a string "$var".
I want to use this to create a php file with a php script...

Is there any way to solve this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `echo 'hello $var';` - no answer required.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php and [php.net strings](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) explain the difference between single and double quoted strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use single quotes:

```
echo 'hello $var';
```

Or escape the `$`:

```
echo "hello \$var";
```